# How to correctly add ssml sound effects?

Tags: node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm making an actions on google project and I'm looking to add some sound effects to it. I wanted to add my own custom sound effect, so I searched and found some mp3 samples but so far every time I put the sound bite in, it just reads the text exactly how its read. So if I had:

```
<speak><audio src='<file>'></audio>Hey</speak>

>> "less than speak greater than less than audio....."
```

I thought originally I had the syntax wrong for audio effects, but when I used a google sound library sample it worked fine.

In a nutshell, can you, or how do you use your own mp3 or wav files for actions on google?

Thanks for the help!

**Edit:** Forgot to add a code sample (if it helps), I'm storing my sound sample in firebase storage. Here's the code:

```
app.intent('sound',(conv) =>{
   const audioSound = '<firebase_link>'
   const ssml = '<speak>Hi, how are you?` +`<audio src="${audioSound}"></audio></speak>
   conv.ask(ssml)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use your own mp3 files for audio responses in AoG platform. However, there are some restrictions. Since the syntax of your code *seems* correct, I assume your URL is faulty.

- The number one rule for your sound URLs is that **the platform only supports HTTPS protocol.** But since you're using Firebase storage, I don't think this is your problem.
- Second possible scenario is that you're not getting the Firebase URL correctly. Are you using [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to retrieve the URL for your files?
- Third and most likely scenario is that **your URL contains `&` character, which clashes with the SSML syntax.** [Here in this article](https://medium.com/google-developers/make-audio-recordings-with-actions-on-google-3094158c2a2d), the author says that you need to encode the `&` characters by using `replace(/&/g,'&#38;')` on the URL string to work properly.

Please let me know if any of these solutions help and if they don't adit your question with more details.